# Can KNIME create a decision tree based on a set?

Tags: decision-tree, knime

I have data that contains sets, for example (this is not my real data):

```
Name,    Type,     Colors
Pikachu, Electric, Red|Black|Yellow
Raichu,  Electric, Brown
Meowth,  Normal,   Yellow|Brown
Togepi,  Fairy,    Yellow|White|Blue|Red
Eevee,   Normal,   Brown
```

My goal is to get a rule-set that determines the name based on the type and color.

I'm using Cell Splitter on the last column. I also have Domain Calculator to create discreet values for each column, because some of my columns may have more than 60 values.
Overall, my workflow looks like this:

[image]

The data looks OK:

```
Pikachu Electric    [Red, Black, Yellow]
Raichu  Electric    [Brown]
Meowth  Normal      [Yellow, Brown]
Togepi  Fairy       [Yellow, White, Blue, Red]
Eevee   Normal      [Brown]
```

My problem is that I can't get the tree to use the Colors set values. My current output rules looks like this - note that the color is not used anywhere:

```
$Type$ = "Electric" AND TRUE    Pikachu 2.0 1.0
$Type$ = "Normal" AND TRUE      Meowth  2.0 1.0
$Type$ = "Fairy" AND TRUE       Togepi  1.0 1.0
```

Is it even possible to use a set as part of the decision tree and ruleset? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add an `Ungroup` node between the `Cell Splitter` and `Domain Calculator` node then I think you get what you want.  Using this, and recreating your workflow, I get the following rule set:

```
$Colors_SplitResultList$ = "Red" AND $Type$ = "Electric" => "Pikachu"
$Colors_SplitResultList$ = "Black" AND $Type$ = "Electric" => "Pikachu"
$Colors_SplitResultList$ = "Yellow" AND $Type$ = "Electric" => "Pikachu"
$Colors_SplitResultList$ = "Brown" AND $Type$ = "Electric" => "Raichu"
$Type$ = "Normal" AND TRUE => "Meowth"
$Type$ = "Fairy" AND TRUE => "Togepi"
```

Comment: Thanks, looks promising. I'll test it tomorrow when I'm back at the office and report back.

Comment: Thanks, this work - *Ungroup* multiplies the row for each value in the set (like a database `JOIN`). I have two concerns though: I'm worried this will introduce a bias for rows that have more values because many other values are also duplicated. Also, this loses the semantic of a single row having multiple colors, but I'm not sure that's a problem for me.

Comment: I guess you could ensure a minimal representation at least by using a `GroupBy` after the ungroup, and put all columns into the grouping.  I agree it would be nice if the rule took each set member as a logical OR so that e.g. the rule for Pikachu became `($Colors_SplitResultList$ = "Red" OR $Colors_SplitResultList$ = "Black" OR $Colors_SplitResultList$ = "Yellow") AND $Type$ = "Electric" => "Pikachu"`- it maybe worth suggesting that to the people over at KNIME - support[at]knime[dot]com - they are usually pretty responsive